# What causes the JSS error "<Hook />'s styles function doesn't rely on the "theme" argument"?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, jss

Unfortunately there are no helpful details when it comes to this error when I run my Jest tests:

`Warning: [JSS] <Hook />'s styles function doesn't rely on the "theme" argument. We recommend declaring styles as an object instead.`

Does anyone know how to locate the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone encountering the same problem I found a helpful plugin for eslint that prints out the exact location of the error: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-jss

The error itself is caused by defining a function inside the `createUseStyles` function instead of simply using an object if only static information is needed.

**Erroneous:**

```js
createUseStyles((...) => ({
    Foo: {
        color: 'red',
        ...
    },
}));
```

**Working:**

```js
createUseStyles({
    Foo: {
        color: 'red',
        ...
    },
});
```